# how to scale image width for device width?

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am getting image in gallery but some image width is not fit in device width so how to set that image width is device width in my `ImageView` but height is same for original image height.

**below is my set image code here**

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
if (null != selectedImageUri) {
// Get the path from the Uri
    String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
    Log.i("", "Image Path : " + path);
     // Set the image in ImageView
      try {
       bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           imgEdit.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
```

Comment: Image or imageView?? you want to show image in imageView with width as device width>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your image view with it.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"

        />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend ImageView, this will match_parent width and proportional height:

```
package com.yourpackage.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DynamicImageView extends ImageView {

public DynamicImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final Drawable d = this.getDrawable();

    if (d != null) {
        final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = (int) Math.ceil(width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth());
        this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
}
```

Then in your XML layout:

```
<com.yourpackage.ui.DynamicImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this and please change aspect ratio as you want

```
 Display display = ((NavigationHome) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
    int height = display.getHeight();
    int sliderHeight = (int) ((width) / 2.4);
        if (height != 0)
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,sliderHeight));
```

Comment: try this code but width is fit and include display width get and set but not working this .. Thnks for time ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Or if you want to fill width

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score -1):

try setting the height to `match_parent`

something like

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

Comment: Why are you changing the original height to 50dp?

Comment: it was just an example